# Code addresses changing in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, disassembly

My issue pertains to the code addresses that VS2015 shows you on the Disassembly
tab when you break the debugger.

The addresses are changing in between runs and there were no code changes made
that would trigger any compiling/linking.

They don't always change between runs, but it only took me only a minute or
two to produce this example where there was a change.

1. I set a break point in an area that gets called almost immediately
2. Start Debugging (F5)
3. The break point hits
4. Clicked on the Disassembly tab and took screen shot (PrtScn)

   ```
       163:                ret = functionName (param1, param2, param3, param4);
   006B9A41    mov     eax,dword ptr [param4 (1330214h)]
   006B9A46    push    eax
   006B9A47    mov     ecx,dword ptr [param3]
   006B9A4A    push    ecx
   006B9A4B    mov     edx,dword ptr [param2]
   006B9A4E    push    edx
   006B9A4F    mov     eax,dword ptr [param1]
   006B9A52    push    eax
   006B9A53    call    functionName (6B9CF0h)
   ...
   ```
5. Clicked Stop Debugging
6. Start Debugging (F5)
7. The break point hits
8. Clicked on the Disassembly tab

   ```
       163:                ret = functionName (param1, param2, param3, param4);
   01729A41    mov     eax,dword ptr [param4 (23A0214h)]
   01729A46    push    eax
   01729A47    mov     ecx,dword ptr [param3]
   01729A4A    push    ecx
   01729A4B    mov     edx,dword ptr [param2]
   01729A4E    push    edx
   01729A4F    mov     eax,dword ptr [param1]
   01729A52    push    eax
   01729A53    call    functionName (1729CF0h)
   ...
   ```

Notice that the high order word in all the addresses have changed.

It was literally a couple seconds in between these two Disassembly snippets

We recently switched from VS2005 to VS2015, this **DID NOT** happen in VS2005 !!!

I would **EXTREMELY** like to know how to stop this and get it to work like VS2005, we
have an email crash reporting system that includes the call stack, which is useless
to find where the crash happened since the addresses are changing at will !!!

Using:
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015
Version 14.0.25425.01 Update 3

Please help!

Thank you

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization

Comment: Thank you very much, now I know what it is called...I figured it had to do with security...

I can now research this further and see if there is anything else I can do other than turning this off...

I found how to disable it: Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Advanced -> Randomized Base Address: **No (/DYNAMICBASE:NO)**...

Not sure how I missed this setting when I was looking for project settings related to this issue